# what is the cauchy-coursat theorem state specificly in word?

Tags: complex-analysis

what is the cauchy-coursat theorem state specifically in word?
Is it calculate the area or the legth,which area and what legth?
please give a example!
And what is deformation of contour?

Comment: You probably mean Cauchy-Goursat. Did you [ask google](http://www.google.ch/search?q=cauchy+goursat+examples)? Clicking this link should give you quite a few hits.

Comment: Deformation of contour refers to homotopy.  This whole machinery is dealt with nicely in John Conway's complex analysis book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-Goursat_theorem

Contour integrals in the complex plane can't be interpreted in terms of length or area.

Comment: But why is it represent as number?